# How to add dynamically an object to a hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

When I use Hibernate query language, how can I add dinamically the object I want to get from the DB?

What I want to reach is somethin like this:

```
......
if(....){
queryString = "from '" + Object1+ "'";
}

if(...){
queryString = "from '" + Object2+ "'";
}

....    
Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
......
```

I tried different kind of syntax but I get errors every time.

Comment: Use CriteriaBuilder for generating custom queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via Criteria API you can easily build dynamic query's...

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Sale.class);
if (startDate != null) {
  criteria.add(Expression.ge("date",startDate);
}
if (endDate != null) {
  criteria.add(Expression.le("date",endDate);
}
List results = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
    ......
if(....){
queryString = "from '" + Object1.getClass().getName()+ "'";
}

if(...){
queryString = "from '" + Object2.getClass().getName()+ "'";
}

....    
Session session = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
......
```

Answer (score 1):

What actually you need is to pass class name. You can use following way to get class name of a given object.

```
object1.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

So in your case you can append this in your query

example :

```
if(....){
queryString = "from '" + Object1.getClass().getSimpleName()+ "'";
}
```